# How can i orchestrate batch executions?

Tags: java, ftp, spring-batch, batch-processing

**Description :**

- I have created a batch that generates some zip files (**ZIP_BATCH**).
- I have another batch that sends those zips via ftp (**FTP_BATCH**).
- I have a main entry from which i can execute any batch i want (**cmd -batch=batch_name**).
- In that main entry class there some control and initialisation logic.

---

**Problem:**

- I want to execute the **FTP_BATCH** after **ZIP_BATCH**.
- I can't integrate **FTP_BATCH** as a job because of the main entry logic.

Is there an optimal way to orchestrate executions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) is probably what you are looking for. It allows you to create a job of jobs and orchestrate them as needed.

Hope this helps.